# Smallest sum of merging list

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, math

Given a list A (size N) of positive integer (between 0 to 1000), you have to merge all the elements of the list by summing 2 elements at a time and adding the previous result.

For example, O = { P, Q, R }, can be merged in 3 different way:

1. first merge P with Q, then merge the result with R
2. first merge P with R, then merge the result with Q
3. first merge R with Q, then merge the result with P

You have to find the smallest sum required to merge the list and return it.

For example, A = { 100, 250, 1000 }, the 3 potential merging strategies are:

1. merge P with Q: 350; result with R: 1350; total: 1700
2. merge P with R: 1100; result with R: 1350; total: 2450
3. merge P with Q: 1250; result with R: 1350; total: 2600

The smallest sum is 1700.

To resolve this, my approach was that, logically if you sort the list and simply add the smallest elements first, it should return the correct result:

```
    public static int Solution(int[] A)
    {
        if (A.Length < 2)
            return 0;

        var max = 0;
        Array.Sort(A);
        var current = A[0];
        for(var i = 1; i<A.Length; i++)
        {
            current += A[i];
            max += current;
        }

        return max;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Edit: This was an online assessment that was rejected without any answer, I'm just looking to improve myself and understand why this is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fails because of the fact that the cost of merging 2 elements adds up to the total cost cumulatively always, if the sort order of merge quantity is **not maintained**.

For example-

```
[20,40,40,50]
```

- Here, let's go with merging as per your sort order.
- Merge **[20,40]**. Current cost = **60**. New array = **[60,40,50]**.
- Merge **[60,40]**. Current cost = **160 (60 + 100)**. New array = **[100,50]**.
- Merge **[100,50]**. Current cost = **310 (160 + 150)**. New array = **[150]**.

Hence, the total cost comes up to **310**.

As you can see, the `60` got added up at the wrong stage(at **[60,40,50]**) while merging, where we could have merge **[40,50]** aiming for a less cost.

**Solution:**

- Use a [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).
- By using a Priority Queue, we maintain the sort order of the cost of the merged files dynamically and can hence aim for a lower cumulative cost. Let's go through the previous example again.

`[20,40,40,50]`

- Merge **[20,40]**. Current cost = **60**. New array = **[40,50,60]**.(`60` goes backwards as we insert it into the priority queue).
- Merge **[40,50]**. Current cost = **150 (60 + 90)**. New array = **[90,60]**.
- Merge **[90,60]**. Current cost = **300 (150 + 150)**. New array = **[150]**.

Hence, the total cost comes up to **300** which is `10` less than the cost obtained via static sort order.